# How do I set an icon for a cmd file?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, icons

I am currently configuring to launch automatically when I open specific files (like php files). I've managed to do that by using a .cmd file packed with Atom.

However, it does not have an icon and every file that is linked to Atom show the wrong icon.

How can I set it to show the right icon? (In this case, the Atom icon).

Comment: make a shortcut to the cmd file, then you can use a custom icon on the shortcut.

Comment: @Moab It works for the shortcut itself, but that icon is not appearing on the other files

Comment: Properties>Change icon>browse, then navigate to the icon?

Comment: That works for the shortcut, but that icon is not used when a file is associated with it and I cannot set an icon to a .cmd file.

Comment: You can't, you can only set icon to the shortcut, or set all `.cmd` to use all same icon, or convert the `.cmd` to `.exe`

Comment: Setting the icon in the shortcut worked in Windows 7 but doesn't work in Windows 10.